# How do I switch to a Spring Data development version with a Spring Boot release?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to port an existing application to MongoDB 3.0. It seems that Spring Data Mongodb (1.7.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) is MongoDB 3.0 ready but I can not find a way to have version 3 driver to get loaded instead of V2.

The second issue is that while making changes `pom.xml` to `1.7.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/PersistentPropertyAccessor
```

What would be the right version combination of Spring Boot and Spring Data MongoDB so that everything works together? I understand that V3 driver is still in beta but would like to get a head start on it considering that MongoDB is in GA as of today.

Answer (score 2):

To control the version of the Spring Data libraries make sure you use Spring Boot's `spring-data-releasetrain.version` property. It will make sure you'll get all Spring Data libraries you actually depend on in matching versions.

The versions we use for the release train are the train names actually. So for the Fowler release train you'd use `Fowler-M1`, `Fowler-RC1`, `Fowler-RELEASE`, `Fowler-SR1` etc. (the latter two not yet released at the time of writing). Current development versions can by obtained by referring to the snapshot version of the release train, e.g. `Fowler-BUILD-SNAPSHOT`.

The version of the MongoDB driver can be tweaked customizing the `mongodb.version` property (currently `3.0.0-beta3` at the time of writing).